All data in one column in CSV file due to formatting of the source file
I receive a CSV file from a colleague that containing sales data. This data I then need to read in to a data table using Powershell.
The format of the file looks like this:
","""","""","""","""","""","""",""Measures"",""Sale in local currency"
,Sale in amount ,
Sale in kilo ,
Sale in liter 
"
Year"",""EAN"",""Retailer number"",""Product name"",""Brand
name"",""Segment"",""Segment2"",""Chain"","""","""","""","""""
"202102,""[EAN]"",""[rn]"",""[NAME]"",""[BRAND]"",""[SEGMENT]"",""[SEGMENT2]"",""CHAIN"",""[LOCAL
CURRENCY]"",""[SALE AMOUNT]"",""[SALE KILO]"",""[SALE LITER]"""

The Sale in local currency, Sale in amount, Sale in kilo, Sale in liter and Segment2 can contain commas.
I have tried importing the CSV file where I skip the first 6 rows and create my own headers using -header @(...). However, due to the first row of data starting with a quotation mark and finale value ending in a third quotation mark, all values are read into the "year" column.
Replacing the quotation marks using -replace '"', ' ' (or exporting using -usequotes never) does not work either as some of the values have commas in them, and thus create extra values that need to be together. Like a number fx. 1.834,23
Replacing the double quotation marks with a single, creates a lot of empty fields at the end of the final value in each row. Something like: "202102,""[EAN]"",""[rn]"",""[NAME]"",""[BRAND]"",""[SEGMENT]"",""[SEGMENT2]"",""CHAIN"",""[LOCAL CURRENCY]"",""[SALE AMOUNT]"",""[SALE KILO]"",""[SALE LITER]""", "","","","","","",""

I'm not sure it's possible, the order of the values seems not coherent. Question: do you know th exact amount of columns each value should have? And it's ALWAYS the same?

Rather than describing all formats and exceptions, try to put an [mcve] in your question with sample data instead of pictures

By what standard is this a valid CSV file? Does it conform to RFC 4180? https://www.loc.gov/preservation/digital/formats/fdd/fdd000323.shtml

Can you paste 3 rows of sample data with header?

I think the “data” you’ve been given is more or less unsalvageable. You might need to talk to your colleague about what a comma-separated file is, and how they suggest parsing the hot mess they’ve given you :-). They might also want to add some unit tests to their code that check the output it generates is valid a CSV file before they sign it off as working…

@sirtao There are supposed to be 12 columns: Year, EAN, Retailer number, Product name, Brand name, Segment, Segment2, Chain, Sale in local currency, sale in amount, sale in kilo, and sale in liter.
It is ALWAYS the same columns, thus my try in just skipping the first few lines and adding the headers when importing the csv file.

if the actual file is formatted EXACTLY(newlines included) like in the example you posted, working on it is going to be quite difficult and you should talk to whoever made the process producing said file. I suggest equipping yourself with powertools when explaining them you need decently formatted CSVs. Activating a large battery powered drill is a great help to emphasys

@iRon Here are 2 lines. Can't give more. Data is modified. Copy to a CSV for view
","""","""","""","""","""","""",""Measures"",""Sales local currency"
,Sale in amount
,Sale in kilo
,Sale in liter
"
year"",""EAN"",""retailer number"",""product name"",""brand name"",""segment"",""segment2"",""chain"","""","""","""","""""
"202407,""234545544663"",""11122233"",""animal food"",""G"",""animal"",""cat"",""Chain1"",""9.443,23"",""88"",""54,46"",""11,33"""
"202407,""234545544663"",""11122233"",""animal food"",""G"",""animal"",""cat"",""Chain2"",""9.233,23"",""99"",""67,46"",""12,33"""

@ArcSet See above comment to iRon for rows of data.

so it the post you did above there is no line breaks. Where are the line breaks located?
